# Problems with Xamarin Live Player?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

I'm trying Xamarin Live Player, using Visual Studio 2017 Preview 3, following this link to setup: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/install/. It seems to work for simple apps. However:

1. I couldn't get the `DependencyService` to work, it just couldn't resolve the dependencies, registered by adding `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(implementorType))]` attributes on the implementation classes.
2. Furthermore, in iOS apps, when I placed a break point in `AppDelegate -> FinishedLaunching` event, the break point seems to be unreachable, could that be the reason that has caused the `DependencyService` broken?

Comment: Since this tool is still in a beta stage, https://forums.xamarin.com/categories/live-player might be a better place to post you queries to